# Remove NAs when using mapply for ttest in R

Tags: r, mapply, na.rm

I would like to do a column-wise ttest between two dataframes in R. That is, `ttest(df1$col1,df2$col1)` ,`ttest(df1$col2,df2$col2)` and so on....The best option here is to use `mapply` or `Map` function. Something like:

```
mapply(t.test,tnav_DJF_histo.csv[,-1],tnav_DJF.csv[,-1])
```

works perfectly  but if one of your df columns has NAs, it fails with this error:

```
Error in t.test.default(dots[[1L]][[1L]], dots[[2L]][[1L]]) : 
  not enough 'y' observations
```

Question: how can I use `na.rm` to get the job done? For example, if a column  in tnav_DJF.csv[,-1] has Nas but no NAs in tnav_DJF_histo.csv[,-1], how can I tell `mapply` to to ignore or skip the analyses for these columns?

Many thanks.

aez.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with `mapply` and an anonymous function as follows:

Example data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=runif(20), b=runif(20), c=rep(NA,20))
df2 <- data.frame(a=runif(20), b=runif(20), c=c(NA,1:18,NA))
#notice df1's third column is just NAs
```

Solution:

Use `mapply` with an anonymous function as follows:

```
#anonumous function testing for NAs
mapply(function(x, y) {
  if(all(is.na(x)) || all(is.na(y))) NULL else t.test(x, y, na.action=na.omit)
  }, df1, df2)
```

Output:

```
$a

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x and y
t = 1.4757, df = 37.337, p-value = 0.1484
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.0543192  0.3458648
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
0.5217619 0.3759890 


$b

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x and y
t = 1.1689, df = 37.7, p-value = 0.2498
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.0815067  0.3041051
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
0.5846343 0.4733351 


$c
NULL
```

P.S. There is no `na.rm` argument in the `t.test` function to use. There is only a `na.action` argument but even if you set that to `na.omit` (which I have) you will still get an error if all the column elements are NA.

P.S.2 If some of the elements of either x or y are NA then the `t.test` function will run properly by omitting those elements. If you want to ignore calculating the t.test if any of the columns contains even a single NA, then you need to change the `all` in the above function to `any`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like

```
t.test2 <- function(col1, col2){
  df <- complete.cases(cbind(col1, col2))
  if(nrow(df) < 3){return(NA)}
  t.test(df[, 1], df[, 2], na.rm = TRUE)
  }
mapply(t.test2, csv1[, -1], csv2[, -2])
```